# How can I update multiple tables with one query using Access ODBC?

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc

I've done a thorough search but can't find an answer to this question. I connect with Access ODBC and need to run a query which updates many tables at the same time based on one value.

Here's what I'm doing at the moment:

```
$DSN="accessodbc";
$DSN_User="myusername";
$DSN_Passwd="mypassword";
$objConnect = odbc_connect( $DSN, $DSN_User, $DSN_Passwd );

$strSQL1="UPDATE table1 SET column1='dup' WHERE User=" . $user;
$strSQL2="UPDATE table2 SET column1='dup' WHERE User=" . $user;
$strSQL3="UPDATE table3 SET column1='dup' WHERE User=" . $user;

$objExec1 = odbc_exec($objConnect, $strSQL1);
$objExec2 = odbc_exec($objConnect, $strSQL2);
$objExec3 = odbc_exec($objConnect, $strSQL3);
```

...and so on for about 50 tables.

This works but is obviously not the best solution resource-wise.  Is there a way to update all the tables with one query?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

While it is fairly unusual to UPDATE more than one table with a single SQL statement, in this particular case you probably can (although implementing this for ~50 tables might be more trouble than it's worth).

For the record, I just tested the following in Access 2010 and for the test tables

```
[table1]
User  column1
----  -------
Gord
Bob          

[table2]
User   column1
-----  -------
Gord
Homer         

[table3]
User      column1
--------  -------
Gord
Quagmire
```

the query

```sql
UPDATE
    (
        table1
        INNER JOIN
        table2
            ON table1.User = table2.User
    )
    INNER JOIN
    table3
        ON table2.User = table3.User
SET
    table1.column1 = 'dup',
    table2.column1 = 'dup',
    table3.column1 = 'dup'
WHERE table1.User = 'Gord'
```

resulted in

```
[table1]
User  column1
----  -------
Gord  dup    
Bob          

[table2]
User   column1
-----  -------
Gord   dup    
Homer         

[table3]
User      column1
--------  -------
Gord      dup    
Quagmire
```

Answer (score 0):

No.  You can't update more than 1 table in a single query.  You can, however, put all the updates into a transaction, and commit the transaction at the end of all the updates.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
   Do all your update statements.
COMMIT TRANSACTION

or, if something goes wrong: 

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Comment: For Access SQL an absolute "No" is actually incorrect. See my answer for details.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Could you explain the code for "BEGIN TRANSACTION", "COMMIT TRANSACTION" and "ROLLBACK TRANSACTION" please? I'm stilla bit of a novice so not sure exactly what you mean. Many thanks.

Comment: Basically, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", opens a "transaction" ... all actions before a "COMMIT" don't actually happen until the COMMIT.  Then for some reason, like an error, instead of doing a "COMMIT", you can do a "ROLLBACK", which un-does all the actions since the "BEGIN".  look here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx for more detail.

Comment: A transaction can be used, but not via ODBC. So if you usng a dao reocrdset, then you can start a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
For I = 1 to 50
   $strSQL = "Update table" & I & " set column1 = 'dubp' WHERE User=" & $user
   Odb_exec($objContact,$strSQL)
Next i
```